# Quarto Book: make body content Wider

Tags: r, quarto

Love love `quarto`. So well developed! Thanks again. I'm using the book output format and it looks great. However I know the screen sizes it will be used on and would really like the main content (id=`quarto-document-content`) to be wider, pushing the toc to the right of the screen. How would I do this? Something like (just close-ish examples)

- sidebar: 15%
- quarto-document-content: 80%
- toc: 5%

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some code on this?

Answer (score 6):

This is now possible in quarto 1.3 (see [prerelease](https://quarto.org/docs/download/prerelease)) using the [grid customization](https://quarto.org/docs/prerelease/1.3/grid.html#overview). The default values are

- sidebar-width:    250px
- body-width:   800px
- margin-width:     250px
- gutter-width:     1.5em

Here an example with approximately what you have looked for:

```
project:
  type: book

book:
  title: "Test Book"
  author: "XYZ"
  date: today
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - intro.qmd
    - summary.qmd
    - references.qmd

format:
  html:
    grid:
      sidebar-width: 200px
      body-width: 1030px
      margin-width: 70px
```

[image]